# When i open visual studio code, it create some private folder in my project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, node-modules, ubuntu-18.04

I am new here in ubuntu, I am facing one issue, I have some projects which is in node and react js, when i open that project from terminal, for that i am using this command `sudo code . --user-data-dir='.'` this command will open that particular project in visual studio code, but when it open that project it create some private folder in my project, why is it working like that ? can anyone please help to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Is this private folder called `.vscode`?

Comment: It create folder like baackups,blob_storage,Cache,CachedData.....

Comment: This sounds like the user data directories that you’re telling vscode to place there with your —user-data-dirs argument. I would try launching without that argument.

Comment: I am getting this error without it : You are trying to start vscode as a super user which is not recommended. If you really want to, you must specify an alternate user data directory using the --user-data-dir argument.